# Jenkins Pipeline: empty changeSets when using P4 as SCM provider

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, perforce, jenkins-groovy

I'm building out a declarative Jenkins pipeline for a Perforce mono-repo to do some lightweight testing and packaging of modules. I want to do the following:

1. Get a list of files changed since last build
2. Determine which modules need to be built
3. For each module, test and package

I have code for 2 and 3, but I cannot seem to get Jenkins to give the list of files that have changed (number 1. above). As per various StackOverflow suggestions and an article on cloudbees (see comment below), Here is my pipeline code:

```
#!groovy

pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                getChangeString()
            }
        } 
    }
}

@NonCPS
def getChangeString() {
    def changeLogSets = currentBuild.changeSets
    echo "${changeLogSets.size()}"
    for (int i = 0; i < changeLogSets.size(); i++) {
        def entries = changeLogSets[i].items
        for (int j = 0; j < entries.length; j++) {
            def entry = entries[j]
            def files = new ArrayList(entry.affectedFiles)
            for (int k = 0; k < files.size(); k++) {
                def file = files[k]
                echo "  ${file.editType.name} ${file.path}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the 'size' of the changeSets always ends up being 0. Is there a way to get at this information when using Perforce as the SCM provider?

Variations I've tried:

1. Using "options { skipdefaultcheckout() }" and manually calling "checkout scm" in a build step
2. Accessing changeSets via "currentBuild.rawBuild.changeSets

Comment: Cloudbees changeSet reference: https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/217630098-How-to-access-Changelogs-in-a-Pipeline-Job-

Comment: People often take changeSets for what they aren't. `changeSet` is the list of files that was modified between this build and the previous one. If the previous one failed and was re-triggered, changeSet would be empty. You may want to get a list of changes _for the given branch_.

Comment: Interesting - so its previous build and not previous _successful_ build? And I assume 'replay-ing' a successful build wouldn't yield any changes?

Comment: Also - regarding your comment about getting a list of changes for the given branch - other than flat out querying P4 directly for this information (via shell script or in the Groovy bindings), is there a Jenkins way of getting this information (similar to the 'changeSet')?

Comment: it's previous build. If you replay a build the changeset would depend on whether there have been pushes or not. To get a list of files changed in the branch we use `git diff`.